# PHP Regex Strings With Apostrophe

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to search strings of the format `[number].word word word` in text,
for example : `1.Test number one`
The pattern i'm using `$pattern = '~\d+[.][\s]*[A-Z]{1}[\w\d\s]+~'` , but the problem is that pattern does not find strings with apostrophe such as `5.That's a valid string`
I've also tried using `$pattern = '~\d+[.][\s]*[A-Z]{1}[\w|\d|\s|\']+~'` but it doesn't work either.

How could I fix the regular expression so it will detect also strings with apostrophes?

Thanks !

Comment: `[a-z]` => `[a-z']` (if you need more punctuation, look at unicode character properties & `\pP`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the [A-Z]' part is for the first character to be uppercase

Comment: Ah, I was to hasty indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following regex:

```
/^\d+\.\s*(?:[\w']+ *)+$/
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/0CBEb8jbnK

#### Explanation:

```
^  -> Start of match
$  -> End of match
?: -> Non capturing group
```

**PS:** You may need to escape single quote in PHP quote if your regex string is using single quote.

Comment: Thanks for the ansert ! How does it work  ? What does the :? do , and why the ^ is needed in the beggining and $ needed in the end ?

Comment: And of course if the quotes being used for the string are single quotes, then you would want to escape the quote inside the brackets.

Comment: @anubhava I think you'd want to change the space-star to a space-plus. Using a star would permit matches of the form `[number].word`.

Comment: @KennethK.: Thanks. Please see linked demo page and try out suggested changes there to see if that works.

Comment: @anubhava Ah, you're correct, and I see the issue. I added [an example](http://www.rubular.com/r/Wa0fJdG3I5) for what I was referring to.

Comment: @KennethK. Yes I see from your example that `[number].word` matches but may be that's what OP also wants.